# Always have undefined when trying to access array in MongoDB result obj

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Good time of a day! Need your help with a simple login/authorization for my personal site running on Express.js. Login itself is handled by Password.js and works well, but something strange happens inside of my auth middleware I cannot access user's roles stored as as an array in Mongo - **it's always undefined** :

```
app.get('/admin', 
         isLoggedIn, //handled by password.js - works ok, 
         hasRole('admin'), //problem is here
         function(req, res){
            res.render('admin.handlebars', { layout : 'main.handlebars', user: req.user });
         }
);

function hasRole(role){
    return function(req, res, next){
        console.log(req.user);
        /*Output:
        {
           "_id" : ObjectId("55a8506c3e1cc054c80eb345"),
           "name" : "user1",
           "passHash" : "$2a$10$E.c1bnIPTXrTMk8nyIeoqO0/0XKRU2pKmaYtLduSvNfngc7nMB7e2",
           "roles" : [ 
                       "admin", **strong text**
                       "power-user"
                     ]
        }*/
        console.log(req.user.roles);
        //Output : undefined...
    }
}
```

Array is presented in console.log(req.user) output but **undefined** if I try to fetch it directly. Well now I'm using a workaround - store roles as a comma-separated string, but could you help me to make it work with array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function hasRole(role){
    return function(req, res, next){
        var user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.user));
        console.log(user.roles);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @wilson, you pointed me into the right direction, I've used object->string-> object  conversion and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to Wilson Balderrama, I've found the solution, it's weird but works:

```
function hasRole(role){
    return function(req, res, next){
        var user = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.user));

        if(user.roles.indexOf(role) !== -1) next();
        else redirect('/access-denied');
    }
}
```